# if $a\cos{x}+b\cos{2x}\ge -1$ find $a+b$ maximum?

Tags: inequality

if for any real numbers $x$ have
$ $.

Find the $a+b$ maximum

My try: since
$$\cos{2x}=2\cos^2{x}-1$$
so
$$a\cos{x}+b(2\cos^2{x}-1)+1\ge 0,\forall x\in R$$
let
$$f(t)=2bt^2+at-b+1\ge 0,-1\le t\le 1$$
and I fell very ugly,maybe have nice methos,Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the stationary points of $f(x)=a\cos x+b\cos(2x)$.

They are given by the solutions of $f'(x)=0$, i.e.:
$$ \left(\sin x\right)\cdot\left(a+4b\cos x\right)=0, $$

so when $f(x)$ has a minimum either $\cos x=\pm 1$ or $\cos x = -\frac{a}{4b}$ (this can happen only if $|a|\leq 4|b|)$.

So, in order to have $f(x)\geq -1$ for all real $x$, it is sufficient to have:
$$ a+b\geq -1,\qquad b-a\geq -1, \qquad -\frac{a^2}{4b}+b\left(2\frac{a^2}{16b^2}-1\right)\geq -1,$$
when the last condition, that is equivalent to $\frac{a^2}{8b}+b\leq 1$, must hold only if $|a|\leq 4|b|$. If we assume that $b$ is positive and $|a|\leq 4b$, we have:

$$ a^2 + 8(b-1/2)^2 \leq 2, $$
so $|a|\leq\sqrt{2}$ and $b\leq 1$. The optimization in this range gives $a=\frac{4}{3}$ and $b=\frac{2}{3}$, for which $a+b=2$. If $b$ is negative but $|a|\leq 4|b|$ still holds, $a+b$ can be, at most, $|a|\leq\sqrt{2}$.
If $|a|\leq 4|b|$ does not hold and both $a,b$ are positive, then:
$$ b\geq a-1>4b-1,$$
so $b$ is at most $1/3$, $a$ is at most $4/3$ and $a+b$ is at most $5/3$. If $a,b$ are both negative the sum $a+b$ is clearly negative. If $b$ is negative and $a$ is positive, $a=k|b|$ and $k>4$, $b$ must be greater than $-\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $a+b$ is at most $\frac{k-1}{k+1}<1$. If $b$ is positive, $a$ is negative and $|a|=kb$ with $k>4$, then $b$ is smaller than $|a|$, so $a+b$ is still negative.

So, among all the functions of the form $f_{a,b}(x)=a\cos x + b\cos(2x)$ that satisfy $f_{a,b}(x)\geq -1$ over $[0,2\pi]$, the argmax of $(a+b)$ is $f_{\frac{4}{3},\frac{2}{3}}$.